# How to change backend URL in Flask Framework

Tags: python, flask, url

### Tech Stack

Python API
Flask Framework

We have developed Python API which then will be consumed by our React UI.

We have URL as follows
http://client-be.domain.com/admin

We want to change url to some random string
http://client-be.domain.com/fvcd9e72

But i am not able to find out where exactly i need to change this in my code.
I can see "admin" folder inside my API code and inside view, code is as follows

admin_views = view1 + view2 + view3 & so on...

So does it means, if i change folder name to random string, my url will be changed?

Comment: [Doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/) explains where urls are. Look for Blueprint objects in your code or decorators at the views. Also, why not to use "search" function in your IDE / editor of choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom url instead of 'admin'. Admin is default url in Flask.

eg:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
admin = Admin(name='app_name', url='/your_string')
```

Comment: You mean, in extensions.py file, right ? After i have changed the code, it worked, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding an argument in your api end point. rest you can handle the situation/conditions in that itself

eg

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<stre>')
def home(stre):
    return stre
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```